# Can quantum effects lead to modification of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry

Consider a modified theory of gravity with the action $$S = \int d^4x \sqrt{g}~R^{\alpha}$$ where $\alpha > 1$. Now, the vacuum equations of motion is same as the usual GR. So, the perihelion of mercury and other tests of GR will not be affected by this. So, I am wondering if there are some quantum effects or other effects that can make $\alpha$ deviate from 1 and we won't even notice from usual GR tests unless we look for it in a collider or something? I am also wondering if $\alpha$ changes from place-to-place. Maybe $\alpha = 1$ in our solar system but maybe $\alpha > 1$ in the core of a neutron star? Is there any field or phenomena that can lead to such a possibility i.e. make $\alpha$ a variable?

Comment: Are you sure the equations of motion are the same as for GR?

Comment: $\alpha>1$ leads to a new scalar degree of freedom. For $\alpha=2$ for example, this is equivalent to GR with a massless real scalar plus a cosmological constant. This new scalar will also couple to matter, so there are experimental constraints

Comment: @Oбжорoв When you consider the Einstein-Cartan formalism then yes they are. Both have $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ when metric compatibility is imposed.

Comment: @Kosm Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @user44690 reference for what? Derivation of equations of motion, or experiments? I don't have specific references, but you can look up constraints on massless scalars, Brans-Dicke theory (scalar-tensor gravity), that kind of stuff.

Comment: @user44690 they are not quite equivalent to GR precisely for the reason I mentioned -- new scalar and a possible cosmological constant. Here you can look into cosmology with R^n gravity: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0410046